# Using the method in two model in one view of asp.net mvc 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have one view in my ASP.net MVC 2.0 project, I want to list the list of employee that I create method `GetProfileCustomer()` in `CustomerModels` and `GetTransaction()` in `TransactionModels`.

How can I import two different of models in a single view?

Comment: Make an aggregate model. And it's be nice to pass some models to partial views.

Comment: But the two models do different works, so I don't want to combine it into one model.

Comment: well maybe i don''t understand you correctly. First of all why do you have methods in models classes? and why don't you want to combine to models in one? Maybe it's not almost combine but to map two models to two viewmodels and aggregate in in one viewmodel which is associated with view

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to MVC as well, and I've struggled with the similar issues if I understand the question correctly.

I've found that you get much cleaner controller code if you design your ViewModels to be as close as possible to the data that the view is using. Your ViewModels can contain lists of other things including other model objects.  Something like:

```
public class TransactionViewModel
{       
    public string dataelement1 { get; set; }
    public int dataelement2 { get; set; }
    //and so on...

    //The Lists
    public IList<Employee> EmpList { get; set; }
    public IList<OtherModel> SomethingElse { get; set; }
    //and so on...          
}
```

In your controller, you construct and initialize your ViewModel

something like...

```
TransactionViewModel TVM = new TransactionViewModel();
//assign basic attributes here..

//make a list
TVM.Emplist = (from blah in context select blah).ToList();

//send it to the view
return View(TVM);
```

Hope this helps and happy to hear any feedback...